# Enforce same node position/layouts for two separate graphs

Tags: python, networkx

We know seeds are used for generating the same graph, and also when preserving the plot-able coordinates of its nodes and edges. Node/edge preservation is possible via `node_positions = nx.spring_layout(G = graph, seed = 5)`. However, when generating a second graph, a different graph seed must be used to produce something that isn't a mere duplicate. In this question's case, the nodes are going to be the exact same as in the first case, and are set-able via `nx.set_node_attributes(graph, dict_of_dicts)`. The edges alone are to be different, to represent the behaviour of nodes across two aspects of their 'personalities'.

I thought that it might be best to generate a second graph using a different seed, and then use the same stored `spring_layout` as before to plot the new edges (albeit causing a bit of a messier drawing) but on top of the same node positions as before. Unfortunately, I am naive and have since realised that this isn't possible as the spring_layout is fundamentally different for each graph.

I wondered what the best method for plotting the same set of node coordinates with two sets of edges might be? I'm not seeking to compound the graph using `nx.compose(graph1, graph2)`, but am in fact hoping to process one graph, plot it, process the second graph, plot it, and achieve a seamless series of output plots due to the static position of the nodes despite the changing edges.

**EDIT**: Post-Answer, this is the original followed by the desired output. Nodes in same positions, but making use of different edges:

**Pre-Answer**

[image]
[image]

**Post-Answer**

[image]
[image]

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly you are struggling. The return value of the layouts in `networkx` are dicts with the nodes as keys and positions as values.
Hence, if the node set of two graphs are the same (or at least all nodes of the graph you want to draw are in the layout dict), you can plot the graph.

So the following plot two different random graphs with the same spring layout - derived from the first:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

g_1 = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(n=10, p=.1, seed=42)
g_2 = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(n=10, p=.1, seed=21)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G=g_1, seed=42)
# pos = nx.circular_layout(g_1)

nx.draw(g_1, pos)
pl.show()

nx.draw(g_2, pos)
pl.show()
```

I'm not sure how many nodes your graphs have, but you may want to check a simpler "edge independent" layout such as circular layout.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion! I suspect the last line of your answer sums it up best - I have 50 nodes, so attempting to shoehorn them into the same spring layout is pretty troublesome. Unfortunately I'd already attempted the solution in your post, but at least that means we wound up on the same page. Here's the output of two different-seeded graphs drawn using the same set of node positions: https://imgur.com/a/CCBMSqW.  It'd be a shame to use a simpler layout as something like spring is perfect for agent-based modelling!

Comment: Scratch that - the error has come on my part! I'd been passing in a non-seeded version from an earlier block of code. Here's the graphs after enforcing the passing in of a seeded version of the `spring_layout`: https://imgur.com/a/6m0kkiX. Thanks for enabling this correction!

Comment: Additionally, if you have any tips on making the corrected graphs tidier - a novice in the field such as myself would be most grateful. First thoughts would be to de-scale the nodes which at present have size represented via degree, but any thoughts after that would be great.

Comment: Just looking at your edited answer, I would remove the node-size degree dependency (if I guess correctly). You could use for this also a colormap on the nodes, but probably both are confusing. If you may not have completely random graphs you could differentiate with color new and old edges.